# Make game appear in game list

Tags: windows-phone

I wrote a windows phone game and currently I'm checking the check-list on MSDN. And since it's a game, I want it to appear in the games hub ant not in the application list. Do I only have to set it to "Game" when publishing in the store or can I write some code to archive that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Genre="apps.games"` in the WMAppManifest.xml file instead of `Genre="apps.normal"` in the `<App>` element.

Try it out first on you own device!

Comment: OK. That works. I had earched the whole App.xaml for something like that, but I was too stupid to look there too.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the category to "Game" when publishing the app. It will automatically appear in the game hub.